# Writing a Unix shell script which will edit a certain line of a .in file

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I'd like to run a program several times with slightly different inputs.  The input file is a long .in file, and I'd only want to edit a single number in a specific line of that file.  So ideally I'd like to write a Unix script that repeats this process several times:

---

1. Edits a line in a .in file
2. Runs a program which uses that file as input
3. Renames the output .nc file from the program and saves it

---

I'm completely new to this sort of scripting, and while I'm pretty sure I can figure out how to do steps 2 and 3 of this process, I'm not sure how to do the second step.  Is it possible to use a script to automate the editing of a .in file, and how would I do that?

Comment: try using the `sed` command to do an inline editing

Comment: as @JoeC said sed would be your best bet using a regular expression that matches that line. Are there any other similar lines in the file?

Comment: If you are sure that the line number will always be the same you can use the `head` and `tail` commands to split the file in half and then concatenate them back together with `cat` passing the first part, new line, and then the second half.

Comment: If you are sure number will always be the same you still should use `sed`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example that should get you started:

```
$ echo cat says meow >say.txt
$ sed -i s/meow/meowwwwwww/ say.txt 
$ cat say.txt 
cat says meowwwwwww
```

Let me know if you need more help.